# Save the state of the calendar and entered data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a sidebar with filters on my site. One of the filters is datetime (I am using the library react-advanced-datetimerange-picker).

If the browser screen size is changed, the sidebar disappears, but a button appears that can open it again.
As soon as the screen sizes change and the sidebar closes (or opens), the calendar disappears, and the entered data is also lost. I would like the calendar and the entered data not lost depending on the screen size.

Can this problem be solved?

Comment: Please include your code in the question. If the link goes away future readers will have no concept of your issue or any solutions offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need move your state to the parent of the sidebar component.

Please check.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-tdd-mztg0q

Comment: Yes, it partially works!
Is it possible to make the calendar not close when the screen is resized? And closed only when the user wishes

Comment: Unfortunately, this calendar library doesn't have `props` for dynamic opening or closing the modal, I just read the documentation and I didn't find any.

Comment: If this feature is mandatory to you need to use library that provide this feature.

Comment: Oh, I had a lot of problems with this library. Thanks anyway for the help

Comment: Regarding the modal window. Is it possible to go another way? - at the moment, the modal opens by clicking on the window with the range (FormControl), but closes by clicking anywhere on the screen. Is it possible to make the modal close only by clicking on the window with the range (FormControl)?

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience. But now I began to check the code you suggested - the functionality that I asked for works, but the data is no longer filtered. Could you check?

Comment: `Regarding the modal window. Is it possible to ....` Unfortunately, Calendar doesn't open and close by css, it doesn't show or hide by for example style `display: none`, if it does we can easily control, but it completely destroyed internal depend on property inside the library component, The developer of the library should expose this property as props to make the user able to manage close and open dynamically, but he didn't

Comment: `but the data is no longer filtered.` I'm sorry, which data? the sidebar has only the Calendar component.

Comment: "I'm sorry, which data? the sidebar has only the Calendar component." There is data on my site that I filter using this filter. When I apply the code you suggested, then the filters are no longer applied to this data

Comment: In my code, I just moved the `time` state to the `App` component, and I turned it a state of one object, instead of two states, I'm not sure if this can make trouble in your original code, Would you please reproduce the issue in codesandbox, so I can have a look.

Comment: A lot of additional code will need to be placed in the codebox. I'll try to figure it out myself. I just noticed that you don't use useEffect, maybe it's because I'm loading filters from the context

Comment: I solved my problem! Could you suggest another question: at the moment, if I select a range of dates (or times) and out of a large amount of data, only those that meet my requirements remain. But in order to reset the selected date (or time) parameters and return the whole list again, you need to reload the page. Is it possible to make any button here that will reset the data without refreshing the page?

Comment: You can reset the date if you set `setTime(start:'', end: '')`

Comment: Sure, I would like.